# jQuery - addClass for one foreach element

Tags: php, jquery, foreach

I have a foreach loop in PHP and I want to change class of one element created by the loop with jQuery.

PHP:

```
<? foreach($todos as $todo): 
    $id = $todo["id"];
?>
<div class="item">
  <a href="?action=do&id=<?=$i?>" id="do">[ ]</a>
  <a href="?action=undo&id=<?=$id?>" class="undo">[x]</a>
  <a href="?action=delete&id=<?=$id?>" class="delete">supprimer</a>
     <?=$todo['text']?>
</div>                           
<? endforeach; ?>
<div class="infos">3 restants</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  $('.do').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('.hidden');
  });
});
```

Comment: You're creating duplicate IDs `do`. That's not valid HTML.

Comment: You have an `$i` where it probably should be `$id`.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `class="do"` in the HTML, otherwise you're creating duplicate IDs.

```
<?php foreach($todos as $todo):  $id = $todo["id"]; ?>
     <div class="item">
        <a href="?action=do&id=<?php echo $id; ?>" class="do">[ ]</a> 
        <a href="?action=undo&id=<?php echo $id; ?>" class="undo">[x]</a> 
        <a href="?action=delete&id=<?php echo $id; ?>" class="delete">supprimer</a>  
        <?php echo $todo['text']; ?>
     </div>                    

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

You got it right for `undo` and `delete`, you just made this mistake for `do`.

Comment: He's creating these in a `foreach` loop, so there's one element for each element of `$todos`.

Comment: Sorry the do id was a mistake, I made differents try before but I change it to a class and it still dosn't work.
I'm not shure that creating a new element with foreach with the same class is a good way to select one on them. May I need to make an incrementation on the class name in the foreach but how can I do ? And how can I select it with JQuery ?

Comment: Using the same class for all of them is the correct way to do this. But I'm not really sure what you expect your Javascript to do, since clicking on the link will reload the page when following the page.

Comment: May the class affectation do not happend because of the page reloading ? Ok so ajax looks to be the good way I think, thanks !

Comment: Nothing you do in the current page lasts across reloading. You can use cookies or local storage to persist variables, or have the script generate the new page with the appropriate changes. Or you can use AJAX.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){
  $('#do').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('.hidden');
  });
});
```

id is a '#'. Not '.'